# Loading CSV using U-SQL is working but select is not working

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am reading a csv file using

```
@serch=
       EXTRACT
         col1 int,
         col2 string,
         col3 string
FROM @"/datalake/in/in.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();

OUTPUT @serch
    TO  @"/datalake/output/out.csv"
      USING Outputters.Csv();
```

It is working fine but when we will do

```
select * from @serch or select col1,col2 from @serch
```

it is not working

Comment: Can you paste details of the error it is giving you?

Answer (score 1):

would be good if you can paste complete statement that is failing for you. Based on what you posted above, looks like you are missing rowset variable. so, your code should be something like @r = SELECT * ... followed by OUTPUT statement.

Furthermore, today, ADLA does not support interactive queries capabilities that allows returning results back to client or user. If that was the intent of your query above, that does not work today. So, the only way to get results is to output rowsets to files. Once interactive is supported, you would be able to do something like you outlined above.

hope this explains and clarifies, Igor